# Efficiently identify changed fields in CSV files using c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, diff

This turned out to be more difficult than I thought.  Basically, each day a snapshot of a customer master list is being dumped by a system into CSV.  It contains about 120000 records and 60 fields.  About 25mb.  Anyway, I'd like to report on values that change between one snapshot and another.  It *isn't* a plan file diff, as it must be matched on the leftmost column value which contains the customer's unique number.  Lines could be inserted/removed etc.  All fields are strings, including the reference number.

I've written a solution with LINQ but it dies with larger datasets.  For 10000 records, it takes 17 seconds.  For 120000, it takes nearly 2 hours to compare the two files.  Right now it uses the excellent and free 'filehelpers' http://www.filehelpers.com/ to load the data, this takes a few seconds only, then.  But detecting which records have changed is more problematic.  The below takes is the 2 hour query:

```
    var changednames = from f in fffiltered
                       from s in sffiltered
                       where f.CustomerRef == s.CustomerRef &&
                       f.Customer_Name != s.Customer_Name
                       select new { f, s };
```

What approach would you recommend?  I'd like to immediately 'prune' the list to those with a change of some sort, then apply my more specific comparisons to that small subset.  Some of my thoughts were:

a) Use dictionaries or Hashsets- though early tests don't really show improvements

b) Compartmentalise the operations - use the first character in the customer reference field and match only against those with the same one.  This probably involves creating many separate collections though and seems pretty inelegant.

c) move away from a typed data arrangement and do it with arrays.  Again, benefit uncertain.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of the discussion below, I'll assume that you have some way of reading the CSV files into a class.  I'll call that class `MyRecord`.

Load the files into separate lists, call them `NewList` and `OldList`:

```
List<MyRecord> NewList = LoadFile("newFilename");
List<MyRecord> OldList = LoadFile("oldFilename");
```

There's perhaps a more elegant way to do this with LINQ, but the idea is to do a straight merge.  First you have to sort the two lists.  Either your `MyRecord` class implements `IComparable`, or you supply your own comparison delegate:

```
NewList.Sort(/* delegate here */);
OldList.Sort(/* delegate here */);
```

You can skip the delegate if `MyRecord` implements `IComparable`.

Now it's a straight merge.

```
int ixNew = 0;
int ixOld = 0;
while (ixNew < NewList.Count && ixOld < OldList.Count)
{
    // Again with the comparison delegate.
    // I'll assume that MyRecord implements IComparable
    int cmpRslt = OldList[ixOld].CompareTo(NewList[ixNew]);
    if (cmpRslt == 0)
    {
        // records have the same customer id.
        // compare for changes.
        ++ixNew;
        ++ixOld;
    }
    else if (cmpRslt < 0)
    {
        // this old record is not in the new file.  It's been deleted.
        ++ixOld;
    }
    else
    {
        // this new record is not in the old file.  It was added.
        ++ixNew;
    }
}

// At this point, one of the lists might still have items.
while (ixNew < NewList.Count)
{
    // NewList[ixNew] is an added record
    ++ixNew;
}

while (ixOld < OldList.Count)
{
    // OldList[ixOld] is a deleted record
}
```

With just 120,000 records, that should execute very quickly.  I would be very surprised if doing the merge took as long as loading the data from disk.

**EDIT: A LINQ solution**

I pondered how one would do this with LINQ.  I can't do exactly the same thing as the merge above, but I can get the added, removed, and changed items in separate collections.
For this to work, `MyRecord` will have to implement `IEquatable<MyRecord>` and also override `GetHashCode`.

```
var AddedItems = NewList.Except(OldList);
var RemovedItems = OldList.Except(NewList);

var OldListLookup = OldList.ToLookup(t => t.Id);
var ItemsInBothLists =
    from newThing in NewList
    let oldThing = OldListLookup[newThing.Id].FirstOrDefault()
    where oldThing != null
    select new { oldThing = oldThing, newThing = newThing };
```

In the above, I assume that `MyRecord` has an `Id` property that is unique.

If you want just the changed items instead of all the items that are in both lists:

```
var ChangedItems =
    from newThing in NewList
    let oldThing = OldListLookup[newThing.Id].FirstOrDefault()
    where oldThing != null && CompareItems(oldThing, newThing) != 0
    select new { oldThing = oldThing, newThing = newThing };
```

The assumption is that the `CompareItems` method will do a deep comparison of the two items and return 0 if they compare equal or non-zero if something has changed.

Comment: +1.  120,000 is really nothing at all.  Even with 60 fields per row, it's about 7 million fields all up.  See my answer for test code.

Comment: I have no words to express how cool this is and how much I appreciate it!  Sorting to make it a single pass was in the back of my head, but the idea of missing records made me think it'd be too complex to implement.  But there it is above, elegant as it gets!  One pass instead of 120,000 effectively.  Thanks again Jim.  Note to anyone using it in the future: I think the CompareTo(NewList[ixOld]) should be updated to NewList[ixNew]. PS. It takes < 10 secs for the 2 25MB files to load and compare, and you are right that the load itself takes about 7 of those 10 seconds. 2hrs->2secs FTW!

Comment: @Glinkot: Glad to help out. The old techniques like this classic merge still have their uses at times. And good catch on the bug. I've fixed it in the response. Those are the hazards of typing in code without giving it the compiler's syntax check.

Comment: Yes, in fact that small bug made me more in awe of how good it was, since you obviously just banged it out adhoc without benefit of compiling/testing!

Comment: @Glinkot: I've written that merge dozens of times in 10 or more differentlanguages over the years. It's one of those things that's good to have in your "bag of tricks."

Comment: @Jim: ... and now added to mine! :)

Comment: @Glinkot: I posted a LINQ solution that involves less code. It should perform well, although perhaps not as fast as the sort and merge. Hard to tell, because the LINQ solution doesn't involve sorting (just building hash tables and dictionaries).

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the extra info!  I might try this also just for interest, I prefer linq when I can use it, just so you can use the same knowledge or code regardless of working with collections or DB's.  Re: your note that Id's must be unique for the LINQ situation, I'd add that they must also be unique for the first solution.  I had some strange results initially (eg removing one row from the 2nd file caused about 6 reports of changes to other rows), and discovered duplicate Id's.  Removing them fixed it.  Bringing in a 2nd field to generate a truly unique key would do the trick also I guess.

Answer (score 2):

This may be best accomplished in a database rather than in code: Create two tables, current and old, import the data from the CSV files into the proper tables and use a combination of SQL queries to generate the output.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.  I was hoping not to have to import them to the DB just to do the compare, but given the performance I need to do *something* about it!  I still struggle to understand why something like LINQ couldn't use similar methods to what a DB would to do its joins; you'd think being in-memory would be a benefit more than anything.  Things like indexing you'd expect could be done in both cases.  Anyway, thanks for the tip mate.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you export that CSV from?

Is your original source a database? If so, why can't you run your query against the database? It will be much more performant than any LINQ implementation.

Comment: It comes from a hideous ERP system which I can't access directly.  I could potentially import it into temp tables if really needed though.  For some reason I thought in-memory performance may be preferable but you're probably right!

Answer (score 0):

Extending Jims answer, a basic example:

```
public class MyRecord
{
  public MyRecord(int id)
  {
    Id = id;
    Fields = new int[60];
  }

  public int Id;
  public int[] Fields;
}
```

Then test code:

```
var recordsOld = new List<MyRecord>();
var recordsNew = new List<MyRecord>();

for (int i = 0; i < 120000; i++)
{
  recordsOld.Add(new MyRecord(i));
  recordsNew.Add(new MyRecord(i));
}

var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
int j = 0;

watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < recordsOld.Count; i++)
{
  while (recordsOld[i].Id != recordsNew[j].Id)
  {
    j++;
  }

  for (int k = 0; k < recordsOld[i].Fields.Length; k++)
  {
    if (recordsOld[i].Fields[k] != recordsNew[j].Fields[k])
    {
      // do your stuff here
    }
  }
}
watch.Stop();
string time = watch.ToString();
```

Takes 200ms to run, assuming the list is in order.  Now, I'm sure that code has heaps of bugs but in the most basic sense it doesn't take the processor long to do millions of iterations.  You either have some complex comparison checks, or some code is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yep, the original way is inefficient alright, mainly because of the iterative nature of it (basically a nested foreach I guess).  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The other have already provided good answers, I'm just going to provide something different for your consideration.

The pseudocode:

```
Read 1000 from each source.
Compare the records.
If changed, store in list of changed records.
If not changed, discard from list.
If not exists, keep in list.
Repeat until all records are exhausted.
```

This code assumes that the records are not sorted.

An alternative would be to:

```
Read all the records and determine what are all the first characters.
Then for each character,
    Read and find records starting with that character.
    Perform comparison as necessary
```

An improvement over the above would be to write a new file if the used records exceed a certain threshold. eg:

```
Read all the records and determine what are all the first characters and the number of occurrence.
Sort by characters with the highest occurrence.
Then for each character,
    Read and find records starting with that character.
    If number of occurrence exceed a certain limit, write records that doesn't start with the character into a new file. // this reduces the amount of data that must be read from file
    Perform comparison as necessary
```

Comment: That's indeed an interesting approach.  It's kind of along the lines I was thinking with the compartmentalising - but having tried this type of thing the algorithm tends to blow out with various if's and exceptions.  Thanks for the idea, I'll keep it in mind!