# Comparing two tables for difference

Tags: c#

I want to compare 2 different tables. Both tables include departure and arrival time with datatype Time like 08:30:00. I want to compare the tables for delays in departure time and arrival time. I was playing around with Except in LINQ but nothing seems to work. I am using asp.net mvc 3.

Let me be more specific. There are 4 tables in total, Train with TrainID, Station with StationID and StationName, Schedule with ScheduleID, TrainID, StationID, ArrivalTime and DepartureTime, and Registration with RegistrationID, TrainID, StationID, ArrivalTime and DepartureTime. TrainID and StationID are foreign keys in Schedule and Registration tables, but theres no relashionship between tables Schedule and Registration.

Schedule table is read-only.

So all i want is to know everytime there is a delay in the Registration table compared with the Schedule table so i can do some statistics on the delays.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to MVC3 to me.

Comment: With your current data model you cannot relate the Schedule and Registration tables other than by TrainId and StationId - this combination might not uniquely identify a schedule so there is no way to map those two tables 1:1.

Comment: I don't think you want to restrict yourself to only the cases where there is a delay; I believe BrokenGlass' query is correct, you want the difference between scheduled and actual on every trip. If a train started 1000 times and had a delay of one hour, once, that statistic would be pretty useless - 999 trips without a delay are important information.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I assume what's required is matching `TrainId`, `StationId`, and the earliest actual `DepartureTime` not earlier than the scheduled `DepartureTime`.

Comment: So a ScheduleID as a foreign key to the Registration table would be a better 1:1 relationship? How would BrokenGlass' query look like with the new given data model?

Comment: I show how to do something similar with LINQ here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240218/efficiently-identify-changed-fields-in-csv-files-using-c-sharp/5240349#5240349

Answer (score 1):

Without your concrete data model one can only speculate, but it looks like you will need a join between the two tables based on a common id. Say for example you are interested in flight arrivals and departures and their delays then you can calculate the delay for each flight, i.e. similar to this:

```
var delaysByFlight = from flight in db.ScheduledFlights
                     join record in db.RegisteredTimes
                     on flight.Id equals record.FlightId
                     select new 
                     {
                        FlightId = flight.Id,
                        Delay = record.RealArrivalTime - flight.ScheduledArrivalTime
                     };
```

Comment: how do you relate both of these tables? Is RegistrationID in the second table a foreign key to the Schedule table?