# Optimisation of INPUT OUTPUT

Tags: c#, .net, file, perforce

I am dealing with files where the number of lines can be at 60000 line.
These files are stored in perforce.
In order to calculate some statistics like number of lines added and number of lines number of comments, I used the method `repository.GetFileAnnotations()` which gives the content of the file, the result is return as a Ilist of FileAnnotation,each fileAnnotation encapsulate a line of this file.
So I am obliged to create a temporary file and to read all the Ilist using a foreach and writing every line in a this file. This make the application not fast enough.
how can I proceed to optimise this mecanism.

```
string tempfile = CreateTmpFile();
FileSpec fso = new FileSpec(FileSpec.DepotSpec(fsd.depotPath).DepotPath, Revision.Head);
IList<FileSpec> fsos = new List<FileSpec>();
fsos.Add(fso);
Options opts = new Options(); opts.Add("-a", "");
IList<FileAnnotation> fas = rep.GetFileAnnotations(fsos, opts);

foreach (FileAnnotation fa in fas)
{
    lines4 += fa.Line;
    UpdateTmpFile(tempfile, fa.Line);
}
```

Comment: I'd consider moving from a file-based data storage to an actual database

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5240218/56778

Comment: Perhaps if i can read all the text of from perforce it will be really a solution because the problem in the data returned by perforce,i am manipulating list which have 60000 member

Comment: nice Library @JimMischel but it can be used when we have a file as input the problem that we have a list of lines as input

Comment: @Ammaedragas: The first thing that code does is load the file into a list of lines. The major processing happens with the lists. It should work well with your lines of lines, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using the `diff2` command?  It'll give you diff output for any two revisions, so you can start comparing lines added, changed, removed, and so on.  It'll definitely be more efficient than parsing the annotations for each line.

Comment: yes i used p4 diff2 and it works very well but the problem persist for the other metrics